# What are the alternatives for this hypothesis test?

Tags: statistics

[image]

I know Type I errors are rejecting the null hypothesis when it is true. So I am 95% sure of the answer to this, just want to get some confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He accepted "the technique is effective", so he rejected "the technique is not effective" - the answer is A